# remove part of jQuery base uri when changing src of an img tag

Tags: jquery, multilingual, base-url

In a multilanguage website when changing the img.src attribute in jQuery, it looks for `base url + src` which becomes something like `http://localhost/app/en/resources/images/img.jpg` assuming `base url` is `http://localhost/app/en/` and `src` is `resources/images/img.jpg`

In fact the `img.jpg` file is not under `en` folder so this should be omitted from the above location. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Try this `location.hostname+"/app/"+src`

Comment: simply replace `en` with empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Give the absolute URL: `http://www.google.com/...../image.png`
2. Give relative URL, two folders up: `../../image.png`